# How to change the images in the html after shuffling them in js?

Tags: javascript, html

I have 3 pics in html and i get them by their classes in my js, shuffle them and i neeed to make them appear on the html ordered by shuffling, but they never change. 
here is my html code:

```js
var frontcards = document.getElementsByClassName('cards');
var myCards = [];
myCards.push(frontcards[0]);
myCards.push(frontcards[1]);
myCards.push(frontcards[2]);
Array.prototype.shuffle = function() {
  var input = this;

  for (var i = input.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    var itemAtIndex = input[randomIndex];

    input[randomIndex] = input[i];
    input[i] = itemAtIndex;
  }
  return input;
}
var playButton = document.getElementById("play");
playButton.onclick = function() {
  myCards.shuffle();
  for (var i = 0; i < myCards.length; i++) {
    document.getElementsByClassName('cards')[i].innerHTML = myCards[i].src;
  }
}
```

```html
<img class="cards" height="300px" width="200" src="images/card1.jpg">
<img class="cards" height="300px" width="200" src="images/card2.png">
<img class="cards" height="300px" width="200" src="images/card3.png">
```

i need the js to change the images src on the html. is that possible?

Comment: Is there any particular reason your img tags are followed by a closing div tag?

Comment: @KhauriMcClain no that was a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are setting the `.innerHTML`, when you should be setting the `.src` to change the image tag's picture:

```
playButton.onclick= function (){
    myCards.shuffle();
    for(var i = 0; i < myCards.length; i++){
        // Change .innerHTML to .src below
        document.getElementsByClassName('cards')[i].src=myCards[i].src;
    }
}
```

Comment: after clicking the button, two of the 3 pics became the same src and after clicking the button again all of the 3 pics get the same src. could you please explain this?

Comment: The shuffle method seems fine. It can hit the same index, true, but it actually swaps these indices rather than overwriting them with the value from the random index, so you'll never end up with a result where multiple elements are the same value, but you will have results where the a value didn't move, which is fine. I think it actually has to do with the fact that `myCards` and `document.getElementsByClassName('cards')` reference the same elements and by changing the src it effects both arrays, thus you end up with duplicated values.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to set the innerHTML when you should be setting the source, true, however you have another problem that might not be obvious. `myCards` and the result of `document.getElementsByClassName('cards')` all contain references (or pointers really) to the same 3 img tags, but in different orders. When you modify the src in one of the arrays it actually changes it in both, so you end up with duplicated sources.

There's probably a handful of solutions that would require to refactor your code, but here's one that won't. If you append the element as a child of the container that has all the cards (in the code below I created one, but it'll depend on your own html setup) then it'll move that particular card to the end of the container. Do that for all cards and then they will be in shuffled order. It just re-orders the elements themselves so you don't need to worry about changing the src (which I removed from my example below to make it easier to see it being shuffled)

```js
var frontcards = document.getElementsByClassName('cards');
var myCards = [];
myCards.push(frontcards[0]);
myCards.push(frontcards[1]);
myCards.push(frontcards[2]);
Array.prototype.shuffle = function() {
  var input = this;

  for (var i = input.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    var itemAtIndex = input[randomIndex];

    input[randomIndex] = input[i];
    input[i] = itemAtIndex;
  }
  return input;
}
var playButton = document.getElementById("play");
playButton.onclick = function() {
  myCards.shuffle();
  var cards_area = document.getElementById("cards_area")
  for (var i = 0; i < myCards.length; i++) {
    cards_area.appendChild(myCards[i])
  }
}
```

```css
.cards{
  display : inline;
  transition : all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.c1{
  background-color : red;
}

.c2{
  background-color : blue;
}

.c3{
  background-color : green;
}
```

```html
<button id="play">PLAY</button>

<div id="cards_area">
  <img class="cards c1" height="300px" width="200">
  <img class="cards c2" height="300px" width="200">
  <img class="cards c3" height="300px" width="200">
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for sharing this. is there any way to show the gui of shuffling. i mean moving the red square to the blue and vice versa!

Comment: I believe you'll have to make some non-trivial changes to your code in order to do that. (i.e. basically refactor it). At the very least you'll have to track and/or set the positions of the cards so that they can even be animated. I found this library called [Shuffle.js](https://vestride.github.io/Shuffle/) that might help you out with this.